# Deploying and Signing jar with java 1.7

Tags: java, security, javafx, code-signing, japplet

Since java 1.7 and new security enhancements, my self-signed applets refuse to run. 
I have tried the sandbox approach but got same results even if i don't require any special permissions from client, just keyboard interaction.

I switched to javafx but the result remains the same. What other solutions exist on running applet/javafx rather than paying for a sign?

Comment: *"in my case i refer to 10yo children"*  In this day and age I wouldn't want my children running code from an unknown source, and that is what you are describing.  *"..with some naive games"*  But the 'bad people' might install spyware, or try to lure the children to their doom.  Without code that is digitally signed using a certificate issued by a CA, there is no way to distinguish between you and the bad people.

Comment: I vote as useful because you bring another perspective of the question and in my case this is a welcomed comment

Comment: Don't use Java. HTML5/JS is the way of the future. Personally I have Java disabled in the browser and I recommend everyone else do so as well.